# Accessing An Android Device With Broken Screen Via ADB and Unauthorized Machine in 2022

Tags: adb, security, fastboot, data-recovery, usb-debugging

I've done a lot of experimentation on this, but can't seem to get anywhere. I'm looking for guidance on recovering data from my broken Android phone(s). It seems like this is going to require some advanced forensics recovery process at this point.
**Is it possible to push files or do any device manipulation if it's put in Recovery Mode/Fastboot/etc?**

So far I've uncovered two methods that have saved two phones:
ONE: Use scrcpy with keys found on an old laptop backup from ~/.android/adbkeys.pub

```
shell$ scrcpy -b4M --print-fps --push-target=/sdcard/Download/ --verbosity=debug -t --disable-screensaver
shell$ adb pull /sdcard/errrrything* /localbox/
```

This obviously only works if you can push APKs via a working debug session. I happened to have a working copy of an adbkey.pub from an old backup I found.

TWO:
Again, finding a good ~/.android/adbkey.pub and copying it to the device via push like so:

```
shell$ adb push ~/.android/adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
shell$ adb pull /sdcard/errrrything* /localbox/
```

This will push your key to the device, but obviously won't work while the phone is booted Normally unless you click "Grant Permission" on the prompt, which is impossible without a screen to see/touch.

***Moving along back to my original question:*** **Is it possible to push files or do any device manipulation if it's put in Recovery Mode/Fastboot/etc?**

If so, I'd think it would be possible to remember the steps and timing for the volume/power buttons and slip in.

**Any help is appreciated! If it helps, these are my phones I'm trying to recover:**

Pixel 3a XL (USB Debugging On. Rooted.) - OS Version Unknown. 2 Years Old.
Motorola Nexus 6 (USB Debugging On. Rooted) - OS Version Unknown. Also 2 Years Old.

Small Note: *I know this question might be seen as me trying to do something "unethical" but I can prove these devices are mine and am not trying to break in to stolen phones or whatever. That said, I understand if you assume the worst - it's probably best to think that way in life. I digress..*

Thank you for reading,

-notdan

Comment: Finding a good adbkey.pub and copying it to the device via push doesn't make sense. If you can push a file you should be able to directly read and extract the files. In my opinion the best option to use an USB keyboard to unlock the phone (lock screen) and to register a Bluetooth keyboard. Without a working screen this is not that simple, best is having a similar device to practice. Once you have the Bluetooth keyboard paired, accepting the adb prompt should be easy.